# Can somebody post the HTML source of SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 on-premises suitebar

Tags: html, suitebar

I don't have my SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 virtual machine with me at the moment (forgotten to pack the external HD, damnit), but I need the HTML output of the on-premises default Suitebar (the top blue bar with the left-hand "SharePoint" text and the right-hand links for "Yammer", "OneDrive", etc).

So, basically, open a SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 standard Teamsite and do a view->source. Then copy everything between the:

```
<div id="suiteBarLeft">
```

and the corresponding closing div:

```
</div>
```

Note: not looking for an Office 365 SharePoint online HTML dump as it is quite different than the on-premises version.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**: All I'm looking for is the HTML output on-premises SP2013 Server creates via its built-in Suitebar delegate for my branding/customizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that?!?

```
<div id="suiteBarLeft">     
 <div class="ms-table ms-fullWidth">            
  <div class="ms-tableRow">         
   <div class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignMiddle">                
    <div class="ms-core-brandingText">
     SharePoint
    </div>              
   </div>               
   <div class="ms-core-deltaSuiteLinks" id="DeltaSuiteLinks">                       
    <div id="suiteLinksBox">                            
     <ul class="ms-core-suiteLinkList"> 
      <li class="ms-core-suiteLink">
       <a class="ms-core-suiteLink-a" id="ctl00_ctl53_ShellNewsfeed" href="http://...:80/mysite/default.aspx"><span>Newsfeed</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="ms-core-suiteLink">
       <a class="ms-core-suiteLink-a" id="ctl00_ctl53_ShellDocuments" href="http://.../personal/.../Documents/Forms/All.aspx"><span>SkyDrive</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="ms-core-suiteLink">
       <a class="ms-core-suiteLink-a" id="ctl00_ctl53_ShellSites" href="http://.../personal/.../Social/Sites.aspx"><span>Websites<span class="ms-suitenav-caratBox" id="Suite_ActiveLinkIndicator_Clip"><img class="ms-suitenav-caratIcon" id="Suite_ActiveLinkIndicator" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23" /></span></span></a>
      </li>
     </ul>                  
    </div>          
   </div>       
  </div>    
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although that's not SP2013 with SP1 because it has "SkyDrive" and "Newsfeed" instead of "Yammer" and "OneDrive" but it's almost what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Ah Ok... I was doubtful because of Yammer... This is the only version I have :)

Comment: That's OK, all I needed was the HTML structure and CSS classs & IDs for customizing. I'll doublecheck on the weekend if SP1 has changed the structure or only the links & titles once I"m back at home having access to my VM, but your snippet is fine to get me started. Thanks again!!